# Whats the efficient way to assign groups in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have many groups such as:

```
BB = ['AA', 'BB', 'CC']
BR = ['LL', 'PP', 'KK']
```

I have a different column:

| df.Sig |
| --- |
| 'AA' |
| 'BB' |
| 'CC' |
| 'LL' |
| 'PP' |
| 'KK' |

I want to create a different column which represents the group:

| df.Sig | Group |
| --- | --- |
| 'AA' | 'BB' |
| 'BB' | 'BB' |
| 'CC' | 'BB' |
| 'LL' | 'BR' |
| 'PP' | 'BR' |
| 'KK' | 'BR' |

I am currently using:

```
df.iloc[df['Sig'].isin(BB), 'Group'] = 'BB'
```

This is not the most efficient, nor is it fastest, way to do this.

Is there any other one liner that I can use to achieve the same, but faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dictionary of lists as starting point, then invert it and [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
d = {'BB': ['AA', 'BB', 'CC'],
     'BR': ['LL', 'PP', 'KK']}

d2 = {v:k for k,l in d.items() for v in l}
# {'AA': 'BB', 'BB': 'BB', 'CC': 'BB', 'LL': 'BR', 'PP': 'BR', 'KK': 'BR'}

df['Group'] = df['df.Sig'].map(d2)
```

Or [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) and [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
d = {'BB': ['AA', 'BB', 'CC'],
     'BR': ['LL', 'PP', 'KK']}

df = df.merge(pd.DataFrame(d).melt(var_name='Group', value_name='df.Sig'))
```

output:

```
  df.Sig Group
0     AA    BB
1     BB    BB
2     CC    BB
3     LL    BR
4     PP    BR
5     KK    BR
```

Comment: do you know which should be faster?

Comment: @norok2 might depend on the data, probably the first one. edit: `map` is faster if one only increases the number of rows, might be different for many groups

Answer (score 2):

You can create a look-up table and apply that:

```py
import pandas 


mapping = {'AA': 'BB', 'BB': 'BB', 'CC': 'BB', 'LL': 'BR', 'PP': 'BR', 'KK': 'BR'}

s = pd.Series(['AA', 'BB', 'CC', 'LL', 'PP', 'KK'])
t = s.map(mapping)
print(s)
# 0    AA
# 1    BB
# 2    CC
# 3    LL
# 4    PP
# 5    KK
# dtype: object
print(t)
# 0    BB
# 1    BB
# 2    BB
# 3    BR
# 4    BR
# 5    BR
# dtype: object
```

Obviously, the mapping can be constructed from the `list`s too.